# Included driver not installed after generalize

Tags: windows-embedded-7

My image contains a driver (intel) for the graphics in a system. After deployment Windows still choses the Standard VGA driver. Manually changing the driver works, without any complaints about signing or compatibility.

What do I need to do to make it pick that driver?

Update: I had a look at setupapi.log, but didn't find any clues there. I then tried a later version of the driver, and windows seems to have liked that better.

Comment: update the image after you manually update driver.

Comment: I do all my configuration on a virtual machine, so that'd be tricky. And I add machine type specific drivers after sysprep, offline using dism.

Answer (score 0):

Include [PersistAllDeviceInstalls](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff716298.aspx) in your unattend.xml.  It tells Sysprep to not remove the devices when generalizing the system.  This is a bad idea if you are deploying to dissimilar hardware in some cases, as it can result in a BSOD during first boot.

I ran into this same issue last year, and it was a bug in the Intel drivers. Basically, when removing the device, it was also removing the driver files from the system.  I believe this was fixed last fall, which is inline with your experience that updating the driver fixed the problem.